# Eliminar nodo de arbol binario de busqueda C

Tags: c, punteros

Buen día, necesito eliminar nodos de un árbol binario de búsqueda en C. Mi código es el siguiente:

```
    void recorridoarbolinterno(Arbol *nodoarb2, Arbol *nodoarb1, Arbol *raiz1, Arbol *raiz2,  FILE* salida){
    int band = 0;
    if (*nodoarb2 != NULL && band == 0) { //EN LA PRIMER VUELTA, COMPARA A A1 con TODOS LOS B, SI ENCUENTRA PAREJA, VA A A2 EN LA FUNC recorridoarbolinorder.
        recorridoarbolinterno(&((*nodoarb2)->izq), nodoarb1, raiz1, raiz2, salida);
        recorridoarbolinterno(&((*nodoarb2)->der), nodoarb1, raiz1, raiz2, salida);
        printf("\nband = %d!!!\n", band);
        if((( ((Judoca) ((*nodoarb1)->dato)) ->edad<18 && ((Judoca) ((*nodoarb2)->dato)) ->edad >= 18) || ( ((Judoca) ((*nodoarb1)->dato)) ->edad>=18 && ((Judoca) ((*nodoarb2)->dato))->edad <18))&&band==0){
            //PAREJA DE MENOR CON MAYOR
            printf("ok1");
            Pareja pareja = malloc (sizeof(_Pareja));
            pareja->estadoPareja = 1;
            pareja->participante1 = (*nodoarb1)->dato;
            pareja->participante2 = (*nodoarb2)->dato;
            //ESCRIBIR DOC
            fprintf(salida, "\n%s %s no pudo formar pareja con %s %s por ser un mayor y un menor \n", pareja->participante1->nombre, pareja->participante1->apellido, pareja->participante2->nombre, pareja->participante2->apellido);

        }else if(((((Judoca) ((*nodoarb1)->dato))->edad < 18 && ((Judoca) ((*nodoarb2)->dato))->edad < 18) && (((((Judoca) ((*nodoarb1)->dato))->edad>(((Judoca) ((*nodoarb2)->dato))->edad)+1)) || (((Judoca) ((*nodoarb2)->dato))->edad>(((Judoca) ((*nodoarb1)->dato))->edad)+1)))&&band==0){
            //LOS DOS MENORES Y LA EDAD DE UNO ES MAYOR A LA DE OTRO + 1 AÑO
            Pareja pareja = malloc (sizeof(_Pareja));
            printf("ok2");
            pareja->estadoPareja = 2;
            pareja->participante1 = (*nodoarb1)->dato;
            pareja->participante2 = (*nodoarb2)->dato;
            
            //ESCRIBIR DOC
            fprintf(salida, "\n%s %s no pudo formar pareja con %s %s por ser ambos menores y llevarse mas de un ano \n", pareja->participante1->nombre, pareja->participante1->apellido, pareja->participante2->nombre, pareja->participante2->apellido);
        }else if(((((Judoca) ((*nodoarb1)->dato))->edad >= 18 && ((Judoca) ((*nodoarb2)->dato))->edad >= 18) && (((((Judoca) ((*nodoarb1)->dato))->edad>(((Judoca) ((*nodoarb2)->dato))->edad)+2)) || (((Judoca) ((*nodoarb2)->dato))->edad>(((Judoca) ((*nodoarb1)->dato))->edad)+2)))&&band==0){
            //LOS DOS MAYORES Y LA EDAD DE UNO ES MAYOR A LA DE OTRO +2 AÑOS
            Pareja pareja = malloc (sizeof(_Pareja));
            printf("ok3");
            pareja->estadoPareja = 3;
            pareja->participante1 = (*nodoarb1)->dato;
            pareja->participante2 = (*nodoarb2)->dato;
            //ESCRIBIR DOC
            fprintf(salida, "\n%s %s no pudo formar pareja con %s %s por ser ambos mayores y llevarse mas de 2 anos \n", pareja->participante1->nombre, pareja->participante1->apellido, pareja->participante2->nombre, pareja->participante2->apellido);
        }else{
            //PAREJA ACEPTADA
            Pareja pareja = malloc (sizeof(_Pareja));
            printf("ok4");
            pareja->estadoPareja = 0;
            pareja->participante1 = (*nodoarb1)->dato;
            
            pareja->participante2 = (*nodoarb2)->dato;
            //ESCRIBIR DOC
            fprintf(salida, "\n\n%s %s SI PUDO FORMAR pareja con %s %s\n\n", pareja->participante1->nombre, pareja->participante1->apellido, pareja->participante2->nombre, pareja->participante2->apellido);
            //ELIMINAR NODOS
            *raiz1 = eliminanodo(*nodoarb1, *raiz1);
            *raiz2 = eliminanodo(*nodoarb2, *raiz2);
            band ++;
        }
    
        }
}
void recorridoarbolinorder(Arbol *nodoarb1, Arbol *nodoarb2, Arbol *raiz1, Arbol *raiz2, FILE* salida) { //PARA VER DE MENOR A MAYOR CADA ÁRBOL
    if (*nodoarb1 != NULL) {
        recorridoarbolinorder(&((*nodoarb1)->izq), nodoarb2, raiz1, raiz2, salida);
        puts("OK");
        //printf("%s %s %d\n", ((Judoca) nodoarb1->dato)->nombre, ((Judoca) nodoarb1->dato)->apellido, ((Judoca) nodoarb1->dato)->edad);
        recorridoarbolinterno(nodoarb2, nodoarb1, raiz1, raiz2, salida); //ACA COMPARO A A1 CON TODOS LOS B
        recorridoarbolinorder(&((*nodoarb1)->der), nodoarb2, raiz1, raiz2, salida);
        }
}

void armaParejas (Arbol *nodoarb1, Arbol *nodoarb2, Arbol *raiz1, Arbol *raiz2, FILE* salida){
    printf("ARBOL 1: \n");
    recorridoarbolinorder(nodoarb1, nodoarb2, raiz1, raiz2, salida);

}
```

El programa lo que hace es tomar una lista de personas con sus edades, y las inserta en un árbol binario de búsqueda basadas en sus edades. Eso funciona, pero bueno es un gran problema el tema de que no se puede eliminar lo que deriva en un seg fault. Si lo ejecuto con gdb me da error en el de un menor con un mayor. Si comento las líneas que llaman a eliminanodo funciona el programa, pero escribe repetido en el documento de salida, lo cual no es deseado.
El problema está en que a la hora de llamar a **eliminanodo**la cual es:

```
Arbol eliminanodo (Arbol nodo, Arbol raiz){
    if (raiz==NULL)
        return NULL;
    
    if(((Judoca) nodo->dato)->edad<((Judoca) raiz->dato)->edad){
        raiz->izq = eliminanodo(nodo, raiz->izq);
    }else if(((Judoca) nodo->dato)->edad>((Judoca) raiz->dato)->edad){
        raiz->der = eliminanodo(nodo, raiz->der);
    } else{ //CASO DONDE ESTAMOS PARADOS EN EL NODO A ELIMINAR
        if(raiz->izq == NULL && raiz->der == NULL){
            Arbol temp = raiz->der;
            freezer(raiz);
            return temp;
        }
        else if (raiz->izq == NULL) {//CASO UN HIJO DER
            Arbol temp = raiz->der;
           freezer(raiz);
            return temp;
        }
        else if (raiz->der == NULL) {//CASO UN HIJO IZQ
            Arbol temp = raiz->izq;
            freezer(raiz);
            return temp;
        } else {
            //CASO DOS HIJOS, PONE A TEMP COMO EL MENOR DE LA DERECHA DE RAIZ
            Arbol temp = minimonodo(raiz->der);
            raiz->dato = temp->dato;
            raiz->der = eliminanodo(raiz->der, temp->dato);
        }

    }  
    return raiz;

}
void freezer(Arbol raiz){
    printf("Oka");
        free(((Judoca) raiz->dato)->nombre);
        free(((Judoca) raiz->dato)->apellido);
        free((raiz->dato)); //ESTO NO VA PQ SE LIBERA AL LIBERAR LAS PAREJAS
        free(raiz);
}
Arbol minimonodo(Arbol nodo)
{
    Arbol current = nodo;
 
    /*BUSCA LA HOJA MAS A LA IZQUIERDA*/
    while (current && current->izq != NULL)
        current = current->izq;
 
    return current;
}
```

Este elimina a los dos primeros pero no al resto, por qué? Gracias

Comment: Hola Gaspar, bienvenido lo primero de todo. ¿Has probado a debuggear primero a ver por qué tienes ese problema?

Comment: Lo hice con gdb por consola, llegando a que me de seg. fault en el if que nombré! No pude hacerlo de otra manera.